# Delphi Apache Link Module request canceled out of memory

Tags: apache, delphi, upload, multipartform-data

i have developed an Apache link module in Delphi, which also contains an upload function via a WebActionItem(Multipart form data).

The upload also works correctly as long as the client does not cancel the request.
However, if the request is aborted, the memory of the httpd.exe will increase continuously.

Within a few seconds the memory reaches the maximum 8 GB and the child-process of Apache is killed.

The strange thing is that my upload function is not reached at all if a request get canceled by the client.
Only the initialization of the WebModule is called when a request comes in.

My questions:

Does Apache take care of the upload of the file and passes it to the Delphi WebModule?

How can I intervene if my upload function in the WebModule is not called at all when a request is aborted by the client?

I am very grateful for any hints, because I'm looking for a solution since hours.

**Edit:**

Example for dpr-File:

```
library mod_restserver;

uses
  {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  Winapi.ActiveX,
  System.Win.ComObj,
  {$ENDIF }
  Web.WebBroker,
  Web.ApacheApp,
  Web.HTTPD24Impl,
  Data.DBXCommon,
  Datasnap.DSSession,
  RESTServer.Service.WebModules in 'RESTServer.Service.WebModules.pas' {webModul: TWebModule};

// httpd.conf-Einträge:
//
(*
 LoadModule webbroker_module modules/mod_restserver.dll

 <Location /rest>
    SetHandler mod_restserver-handler
 </Location>
*)
//
// Diese Einträge setzen voraus, dass das Ausgabeverzeichnis für dieses Projekt das apache/modules-Verzeichnis ist.
//
// httpd.conf-Einträge sollten unterschiedlich sein, wenn das Projekt auf eine der folgenden Weisen geändert wird:
//   1. Der Name der Variable TApacheModuleData wird geändert.
//   2. Das Projekt wird umbenannt.
//   3. Das Ausgabeverzeichnis ist nicht das Verzeichnis apache/modules.
//   4. Die Erweiterung der dynamischen Bibliothek ist von der Plattform abhängig. Verwenden Sie für Windows .dll und für Linux .so.
//

// Exportierte Variable deklarieren, damit Apache auf dieses Modul zugreifen kann.
var
  GModuleData: TApacheModuleData;
exports
  GModuleData name 'webbroker_module';

procedure TerminateThreads;
begin
  TDSSessionManager.Instance.Free;
  Data.DBXCommon.TDBXScheduler.Instance.Free;
end;

begin
{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  CoInitFlags := COINIT_MULTITHREADED;
{$ENDIF}
  Web.ApacheApp.InitApplication(@GModuleData);
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.WebModuleClass := WebModuleClass;
  TApacheApplication(Application).OnTerminate := TerminateThreads;
  Application.Run;
end.
```

And example for the webmodule:

```
unit RESTServer.Service.WebModules;

interface

uses
  {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  Winapi.ActiveX,
  System.Win.ComObj,
  {$ENDIF }
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes,
  Web.HTTPApp, Web.WebFileDispatcher, Web.HTTPProd,
  Datasnap.DSHTTPWebBroker, Datasnap.DSServer, DataSnap.DSAuth, Datasnap.DSCommonServer,
  IPPeerServer, IdContext, Datasnap.DSHTTP, ReqMulti, JSON, System.IOUtils;

type
  TwebModul = class(TWebModule)
    dsServer: TDSServer;
    procedure WebModule1DefaultHandlerAction(Sender: TObject;
      Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
    procedure webModulfileUploadAction(Sender: TObject; Request: TWebRequest;
      Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);

  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }

  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

var
  WebModuleClass: TComponentClass = TwebModul;

implementation


{$R *.dfm}

uses
  Web.WebReq, Datasnap.DSSession;

procedure TwebModul.WebModule1DefaultHandlerAction(Sender: TObject;
  Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  Response.Content :=
    '{"return":-1, "result":0, "msg":"ressource unknown"}';
end;

procedure TwebModul.webModulfileUploadAction(Sender: TObject;
  Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
var
  joResponse: TJSONObject;
  iCount,
  iReturn, iResult: Integer;
  sPath, s: String;
  aFile: TAbstractWebRequestFile;
  ms: TMemoryStream;
begin
  joResponse := TJSONObject.Create;
  iReturn := 0;
  iResult := 0;
  try
    try
      if Request.Files.Count > 0 then
      begin
        for iCount := 0 to Request.Files.Count - 1 do
        begin
          aFile := Request.Files.Items[iCount];
          ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
          try
            sPath := 'C:\Data\test.txt';
            //if not DirectoryExists(sPath) then
            //  TDirectory.CreateDirectory(sPath);
            aFile.Stream.Position := 0;
            ms.CopyFrom(aFile.Stream, aFile.Stream.Size);
            ms.SaveToFile(sPath);
          finally
            ms.free;
          end;
          Inc(iResult);
        end;
      end;
    except
      on E: Exception do
      begin
        s := E.Message;
        iReturn := 2;
        iResult := 0;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    joResponse.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('return', TJSONNumber.Create(iReturn)));
    joResponse.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('result', TJSONNumber.Create(iResult)));

    Response.ContentType := 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
    Response.Content := joResponse.ToJSON;
  end;
end;

initialization
  CoInitialize(nil);

finalization
  CoUninitialize;

end.
```

Comment: How about a [mcve]?

Comment: There may be a bug in WebBroker. What version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Delphi 10.3 Update 1

Comment: I've added a simple example of the code i use.

Comment: You could try a CGI instead of an Apache module. At least it won't kill the Apache process.

Comment: I tried to switch to a function which gets the file over a json request with base64 encoded. This causes the same issue.